# Does aws nat gateway has an equivalent in GCP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, nat, google-cloud-dataflow, amazon-elb

I'd like my GCP dataflow instances to reach a public ELB in AWS without having to manage manually the ACL in the ELB security group.

I thought about redirecting my dataflow traffic through only one GCP public IP so I could restrict the AWS ELB to this IP.

I know I can do something like this in AWS using a NAT Gateway, but I can't find anything similar in GCE. Am I wrong?

I see how to deploy a logical NAT in GCE but I don't want to have a SPOF and have to manage the NAT service (which means making it HA mainly).

We also already have a vpn connection between GCE and AWS, maybe it could help?

Has someone a solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no managed NAT service in GCP.
You can deploy such gateway yourself following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#natgateway)

If you want to make it high available you can deploy a few NAT gateways and use [internal load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/internal/), with that it won't be SPOF.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for seems Google Cloud NAT:
https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview